# Playing HTML5 Video in WebView iframe on Android

Tags: android, html, video, webview

I am attempting to follow guidance listed [here](https://inducesmile.com/android/embed-and-play-youtube-video-in-android-webview/) in order to play videos from a ustream embed in my app.  The answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569664/android-html5-video-in-webview) says that it should work for me in 4.4 but is not playing anything back on my test Droid Max running 4.4.4

I have looked at several answers posted online, but all of them either utilize deprecated code or no longer work.  I have enabled hardware acceleration and have the following code in java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webcontent);
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); // Set Chrome Client
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); //Set Webview Client
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Welcome.html");
    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}
```

Comment: the html code is a simple ustream embed iframe.  I can post if needed

Comment: If it helps, there may be a postmessage issue based on what other posters have mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this works for you

```
  WebView wb;
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }
}
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);
    wb=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wb.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    // wb.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    wb.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    wb.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=playlist");
}
```

}

Comment: No. Some of that code is deprecated and does not compile

Comment: Let me ammend my previous statement.  Your code works for me if I use your link.  Ustream does not.  the site I am trying to reach can be found here [https://www.ustream.tv/combined-embed/10786920?social=0&videos=gallery&videosCount=6&html5ui](https://www.ustream.tv/combined-embed/10786920?social=0&videos=gallery&videosCount=6&html5ui)